# How Do I search for MODIS data using pyModis?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, pymodis

I want to download the latest Modis vegetation Index Data(MODIS/Terra Vegetation Indices 16-Day L3 Global 250m SIN Grid V006) , whenever it is available for my Study Area.

I know the Tile that my data falls in, but I can't figure out how to search, and get a list of available tiles in a Given Time period.

Is there a sample script which shows how you can search for Modis data using pyModis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of pyModis, this can be done by using the [LAADS Web Service (LWS) Classic API](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/tools-and-services/lws-classic/api.php)

> LAADS Web Service Classic is a SOAP and REST based Application
>   Programming Interface (API) that allows users to search, order, and
>   download MODIS Level-1 and atmosphere data products through a
>   programmable interface.

You will have to first get a List of available scenes, by making a Query like:
`http://modwebsrv.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/axis2/services/MODAPSservices/searchForFiles?product=MOD13Q1&start=2018-07-25&stop=2018-08-23&north=07&south=07&west=25&east=25&coordsOrTiles=tiles`

which returns:

```
<mws:searchForFilesResponse 
    xmlns:mws="http://modapsws.gsfc.nasa.gov/xsd">
    <return>3252975585</return>
</mws:searchForFilesResponse>
```

You will have to pick up this Id, and use it in the following request:
`http://modwebsrv.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/axis2/services/MODAPSservices/getFileProperties?fileIds=3252975585`

which will return:

```
<mws:getFilePropertiesResponse 
    xmlns:mws="http://modapsws.gsfc.nasa.gov/xsd">
    <return mws:type="mws:FileProperties">
        <mws:checksum>1186137567</mws:checksum>
        <mws:fileId>3252975585</mws:fileId>
        <mws:fileName>MOD13Q1.A2018209.h25v07.006.2018227125549.hdf</mws:fileName>
        <mws:fileSizeBytes>179909282</mws:fileSizeBytes>
        <mws:fileType>MOD13Q1</mws:fileType>
        <mws:ingestTime>2018-08-15 16:56:15.578021</mws:ingestTime>
        <mws:online>true</mws:online>
        <mws:startTime>2018-07-28 00:00:00.0</mws:startTime>
    </return>
</mws:getFilePropertiesResponse>
```